# ASP.NET Formauthentication.Signout() not working

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication for a web site I am building and it works out pretty well except I cannot get the auth cookie to delete or expire.  I have tried any number of methods and none of them seem to work.  Here is what I create the cookie.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.userName, false);

                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("user");
                    Response.Cookies["user"].Value = model.userName;
```

Now the second cookie isn't an actual authcookie, that is used for some of the inner workings of the site per client request.  This next part are various things I have tried to delete the cookie.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Roles.DeleteCookie();
        Session.Clear();
        //Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
        //foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        //{
        //    Request.Cookies.Remove(cookie);
        //}
        //foreach (var cookie in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
        //{
        //    Response.Cookies.Remove(cookie);
        //}
        //Session.Abandon();

        //// clear authentication cookie
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["user"];
        string userName = cookie.Value;
        cookie.Expires.AddDays(-30);

        //HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        //cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        //Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

        //HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["user"];
        //cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        //HttpCookie user = Request.Cookies["user"];
        //role.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        //Response.Cookies["user"].Value = null;
        Session.Abandon();
```

I just cut and paste the entire thing in there, some of it is commented out now but at some point and time I have attempted to use each method in that code to remove the cookie.  Some of these attempts were just guesses since I have been at this for a while.  Last here is the auth section of my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="90" name=".ASPXFORMS" />
</authentication>
```

Any input as to what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
```

Before calling session.  I generally place this in a separate method to make it easy to call from multiple places.  Something like this:

```
internal void SignOut(HttpContext context)
{
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

     HttpSessionState session = context.Session;

     if(session != null)
     {
          session.Abandon();
     }
}
```